# Execute Value URL page change when user clicks input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a dynamic form, with different options, within each option is a Value that contains a URL. Once the user selects the option and then clicks the input button is it possible for them to be re-directed to the URL in the Value? Here's the current code I have.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    location.href = $("#decision-form select").val();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="decision-form" action="" method="post">
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <select name="age_select" id="age_select" class="age">
      <option value="age-fill">Select Your Age</option>
      <option value="https://stackoverflow.com/">8</option>
      <option value="DIFFERENT-URL">9</option>
      <option value="DIFFERENT-URL">10</option>
      <option value="DIFFERENT-URL">11</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <input type="submit" value="Find Out More" id="submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes. Please show us your JavaScript attempt.

Comment: yes, prevent default behaviour of submitting form and then use window.location.href with the selected option. I would have adjusted your code if you showed what you tried

Comment: Sorry - I missed out the jQuery. I have added that now, but definitely think I've done it wrong.

Comment: Try `$("#submit").click`  and to get the value use `$("#decision-form select").val();`

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m I've done that, but that doesn't seem to work - have I done something wrong?

Comment: You still need the location.href bit, why did you remove that?  just the "get the value" part didn't need `option:selected`, still need to use the value you "get"

Comment: @freedomn-m Sorrry!! I've amended now, but I still can't get it to work :(

Comment: I've fixed your snippet to include jquery.  The `form` is still POSTing *before* the redirect occurs.  Add a `return false` to the `click` event.

Comment: I've got it working now - thanks SO much for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're getting the selected option's value but not doing anything with it.

```
$("#decision-form select").val();
```

That doesn't assign it to anything. You need to feed it to `location.href` to change the URL.

```
location.href = $("#decision-form select").val();
```

Comment: Thanks, I've amended the code above to that but I still can't get it work - have I formatted something wrong?

Comment: Nope, that looks correct (although you should listen to the form's submit event, rather than the button's click event, but that's not your problem.) Can you reproduce in a Fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need the form because you aren't going to submit it
Let's do what you want - redirect on click, and we are going to use a link with a href value changed by JS anytime value of your select is changed

```js
$(function() {
  $("#age_select").change((event) =>
    $("#submit").attr("href", event.target.value)
  )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-12">
  <select name="age_select" id="age_select" class="age">
    <option value="age-fill">Select Your Age</option>
    <option value="https://stackoverflow.com/">8</option>
    <option value="DIFFERENT-URL">9</option>
    <option value="DIFFERENT-URL">10</option>
    <option value="DIFFERENT-URL">11</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-12">
  <a id="submit" href="age-fill">Find out More</a>
</div>
```

If you still want to have a form and a submit button, let's change the action of the form to the URL you want to redirect. Use GET method for redirect. Delete name attribute from your select to exclude it from params. Bind event on change, like previous example shows.

```js
$(function() {
   $("#age_select").change((event) =>
    $("#decision-form").attr("action", event.target.value)
  )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="decision-form" action="" method="get">
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <select id="age_select" class="age">
      <option value="age-fill">Select Your Age</option>
      <option value="https://stackoverflow.com/">8</option>
      <option value="DIFFERENT-URL">9</option>
      <option value="DIFFERENT-URL">10</option>
      <option value="DIFFERENT-URL">11</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <input type="submit" value="Find Out More" id="submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```